# SmartGit: How to include ignored files in stash

Tags: git, git-stash, smartgit

It appears that when we use SmartGit to create a stash before doing a checkout on another branch (with the "include untracked files" option checked) then SmartGit does not include the ignored files in the stash. It will call:

```
git stash --include-untracked ....
```

I don't see an obvious way to ensure SmartGit instead calls this to include ignored files:

```
git stash --all ....
```

We noticed this because my colleague lost a whole project that she had ignored in the repository.

Comment: I can confirm that SmartGit does not support --all ... though I'm wondering how you could lose ignored files with --untracked as they should simply remain in the repository according to the Git docs.